# Как импортировать свой модуль в IDLE - изменение PYTHONPATH в терминале не отражается в sys.path в IDLE?

Tags: python

Никак не могу импортировать свой модуль в IDLE. Добавляю путь к своему модулю в PYTHONPATH в терминале, запускаю в терминале питон - и модуль импортируется. Запускаю IDLE - а там импорт не работает (ошибка - нет модуля с таким именем). Проверяю значения sys.path в терминале и IDLE - они разнятся. В IDLE отсутствует мой путь, введенный в терминале. Можно ли решить эту проблему?

Comment: Какая система?.

Comment: Система Линукс Минт

Comment: Нужно добавить путь в файл ~/.bashrc. Добавление пути в терминале действует только в терминале и только на текущую сессию.

Comment: Как - вручную или с помощью определенной команды? (я малоопытный)

Comment: В обычном текстовом редакторе можно.

Comment: Предложенный вариант оказался не для меня - я не нашел место, куда должен внести свой путь . Сказалось отсутствие опыта и соответсвующих знаний.

Answer (score 1):

Методом проб и ошибок нашел для себя такой выход. В терминале установил значение переменной PYTHOPATH:
$export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/'path_my'
Проверил:
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
path-my
Именно после этого и именно из этого же терминала запустил свой IDLE:
$idle3
И тогда заработал импорт из моего пути.